# How to translate a string of zeros and ones into bitset?

Tags: java, bit, bitset

So I have this code snippet to translate a string into bitset.

```
    String huffmancode = "0010110100";
    char[] ch = huffmancode.toCharArray();

    BitSet bs = new BitSet();
    for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++)  {
        if (ch[i] == '1') {
            bs.set(i);
        }
    }
```

My question is how to determine the boundary / size / length of the bitset given that the first and the last indexes of huffman code were 0's ?

Comment: what is wrong with `bs.length ();`

Comment: since bitset does not as such set 0's I would not get the length() == huffmanCode.length();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following bitset contains [0,1] in order and the last line of the following code prints out `2`, the length of the bitset.

```
BitSet bs = new BitSet();

bs.set(0, false);
bs.set(1, true);

System.out.println(bs.length());
```